# Call Python class methods from the command line

Tags: python, class, methods, sys

so I wrote some class in a Python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv
filepath = sys.argv[1]

class test(object):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath

    def method(self):
        list = []
        with open(self.filepath, "r") as table:
            reader = csv.reader(table, delimiter="\t")
            for line in reader:
                list.append[line]
```

If I call this script from the command line, how am I able to call method?
so usually I enter: $ python test.py test_file
Now I just need to know how to access the class function called "method".

Comment: be a little more clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Run function from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd create an instance of the class, then call the method:

```
test_instance = test(filepath)
test_instance.method()
```

Note that in Python you don't *have* to create classes just to run code. You  could just use a simple function here:

```
import sys
import csv

def read_csv(filepath):
    list = []
    with open(self.filepath, "r") as table:
        reader = csv.reader(table, delimiter="\t")
        for line in reader:
            list.append[line]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_csv(sys.argv[1])
```

where I moved the function call to a `__main__` guard so that you can *also* use the script as a module and import the `read_csv()` function for use elsewhere.

Comment: I know that I could use the function without writing it inside a class but I was simply curious about how it would be possible to do this:)

Answer (score 3):

Open Python interpreter from the command line.

```
$ python
```

Import your python code module, make a class instance and call the method.

```
>>> import test
>>> instance = test(test_file)
>>> instance.method()
```