# Running a python method/function directly from a file

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to directly run a python function directly from a file by just mentioning the filename followed by the function in a single line.

For example, lets say I have a file '***test.py***' with a function '***newfunction()***'.

----------test.py-----------

```
def newfunction():
     print 'welcome'
```

Can I run the newfunction() doing something similar to this.

```
  python test.py newfunction
```

I know how to import and to call functions etc.Having seen similar commands in django etc (`python manage.py runserver`), I felt there is a way to directly call a function like this. Let me know if something similar is possible.

I want to be able to use it with django. But an answer that is applicable everywhere would be great.

Comment: I think your question may already be answered by [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line)

Comment: That is not actually what I want to know. I want to know if it can be done in a  similar way to the 'python manage.py migrate' etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with **`globals()`** and **`arguments (sys.argv)`**:

```
#coding:utf-8

import sys

def moo():
    print 'yewww! printing from "moo" function'

def foo():
    print 'yeeey! printing from "foo" function'

try:
    function = sys.argv[1]
    globals()[function]()
except IndexError:
    raise Exception("Please provide function name")
except KeyError:
    raise Exception("Function {} hasn't been found".format(function))
```

**Results:**

```
➜ python calling.py foo
yeeey! printing from "foo" function

➜ python calling.py moo
yewww! printing from "moo" function

➜ python calling.py something_else
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calling.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise Exception("Function {} hasn't been found".format(function))
Exception: Function something_else hasn't been found

➜ python calling.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calling.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise Exception("Please provide function name")
Exception: Please provide function name
```

Comment: @MukundGandlur why can't you? Didn't it helped?

Comment: It's great to know it helps. I'm glad it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

All those commands like `migrate`, `runserver` or `dbshell` etc. are implemented like how it was described in that link:

> Applications can register their own actions with **manage.py**. To do this, just add a **management/commands** directory to the application.
>
> Django will register a manage.py command for each Python module in that directory whose name doesn’t begin with an underscore.