# Run Python function with input arguments from command line

Tags: python, function, input, command-line, arguments

My function convert.py is:

```
def convert(a,b)
  factor = 2194.2
  return (a-b)*factor
```

How do I run it from the command line with input arguments `a` and `b`?
I tried:

```
python convert.py 32 46
```

But got an error.

I did try to find the answer online, and I found related things but not the answer:

1. [Run function from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line) (Stack Overflow)
2. [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/command-line-arguments-in-python)  (Stack Overflow)
3. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/
4. http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to/

Also, where can I find the answer myself so that I can save this site for more non-trivial questions?

Comment: What error have you got?

Comment: replace `a` and `b` with `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`, also checkout `argparse`

Comment: Check [this document](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1382/parsing-command-line-arguments#t=201608171014404401577) out.

Comment: Your added links should have helped!

Comment: @petres: Which one in particular?

Comment: @petres: Which one?

Comment: the third link is quite good introduction in using command line args in python

Comment: @Chris_Rands a and b have to be replaced by sys.arg[2] and [3] if the function is in a script which should be the case, not by [1] and [2]. Wait, you are right, because the function is not called from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a Python module for this sort of thing called [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), which allows you to do really fancy things around command line flags. You don't really need that - you've just got two numbers on the command line. This can be handled really naively.

Python allows you direct access to the command line arguments via an array called `sys.argv` - you'll need to `import sys` first. The first element in this array is always the program name, but the second and third will be the numbers you pass in `i.e. sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`. For a more complete example:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print 'Didnt supply to numbers'
a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
```

Of course you'll need some error checking around making sure they are actuall integers/floats.

A bit of extra reading around sys.argv if you're interested [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

To be complete, we can give an argparse example as well:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('numbers', type=float, nargs=2,
                            help='Things to perform actions on')
args = parser.parse_args()

a = args.numbers[0]
b = args.numbers[1]

print a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import sys
def convert(a,b):
    factor = 2194.2
    return (a-b)*factor
print(convert(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))
```

If that is all what should do the script, you dont have to define a function:

```
import sys
factor = 2194.2
print((int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])*factor)
```

If you don't want to change your file (aside from the fact that you have to add the colon after the function definition), you could follow your first linked approach:

```
python -c 'import convert, sys; print convert.convert(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])'
```