# How to run python script with arguments in python 3 interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, interpreter

I am using PyZo(with python3.5) and dont know **how to run a script with arguments** from PyZo's python interpreter - or **from python interpreter** in general. I found following working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3) for python3 but dont know how to pass arguments (e.g. csv file input_data.csv) to the script

```
>>> exec(open("./script.py").read())
```

This is working in iPython:

```
In [1]: run script.py input_data.csv
```

What is the python 3 equivalent of the iPython command above ?

Thanks

---

Note 1

When running a script with arguments from an OS command line you type this:

`$ python script.py input_data.csv`

What I would expect when using python interpreter is being able to run a python script e.g. like this:

`>>> script.py input_data.csv`

i.e. without [calling python executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807168/3096593), or using ['exec(open("./script.py").read())'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577427/3096593), etc.
For me running a script with arguments is very fundamental thing to do but apparently not for majority of users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Run function from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line)

Comment: i want to run a script from a python interpreter not OS command line

Comment: The "python3 equivalent" is either (i) to install IPython for Python 3 and just use it,  or (ii) (somewhat more clunkily) set `sys.argv=['script.py', 'input_data.csv']` by hand before executing the content of `script.py`.   But I think what you really want is the ***PyZo*** equivalent of IPython's  `run`.  I wouldn't be surprised to learn that that exists in some form but it's a PyZo-specific question.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run('python script.py input_data.csv', shell=True)
```

Comment: i am liking this Claudio, have not seen this elsewhere

Comment: Sounds like a nice idea, but it fails in what I see as a key benefit of running something from interpreter, the ability to further access/experiment with the variables afterwards, as this is spawning a separate process.