# Publish to a topic using Google Cloud Pubsub within Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am quite new to the GCP platform. I wanted to find out if it were possible to publish to a Google Cloud Pubsub topic from within a Preemptible Compute Engine VM's shutdown script, other than performing REST calls to the PubSub API?

I would like to notify myself each time a Compute Engine Preemptible VM has been scheduled to be preempted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/pubsub-logging-pvm-shutdowns). Briefly, it uses the Python Client Library to publish to a specific topic ([more here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher), including other languages). The script and credentials are saved in an image to be able to automate it for future VMs. Then you can just invoke the script with the `--metadata` flag where the key would be `shutdown-script` and the value the bash script that calls the code. For example:

```
gcloud compute instances create <instance-name> --preemptible --image <image-name> \
--zone <zone> --metadata shutdown-script="#! /bin/bash
    sudo su -
    python /path/to/script.py"
```

Alternatively, instead of saving the image and pointing to the Python script, you could just dump the python code into the bash shutdown script with the `-c` argument as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Even easier, just set your shutdown script to run [`gcloud pubsub topics publish TOPIC [--message=MESSAGE]`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/publish).

Comment: Thanks Guillem I see what you are getting at, but @Jofre method is pretty simple! Can't believe I forgot about that!