# Python : extract parameters created with argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have a file called simple_example.py, which consists of 2 functions:

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse


class simple:

    @staticmethod
    def func1():

        # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("-n", "--name", help="name of the user", default='host')
        ap.add_argument('-num', '--number', required=True, help='choose a number')
        args = vars(ap.parse_args())

        # display a friendly message to the user
        print("Hi there {}, it's nice to meet you! you chose {}".format(args['name'], args['age']))


    @staticmethod
    def func2():

        # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("-n", "--name", help="name of the user", default='host')
        ap.add_argument('-num', '--number', required=True, help='choose a number')
        ap.add_argument("-g", "--greet", help="say greetings", default='hello')
        args = vars(ap.parse_args())

        # display a friendly message to the user
        print("{} there {}, it's nice to meet you! you chose {}".format(args['greet'], args['name'], args['age']))
```

I'd like to be able to call either func1() or func2() from the command line, so, I created another file called pyrun.py from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130994/python-run-function-from-the-command-line/29130994#29130994)

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# make executable in bash chmod +x PyRun

import sys
import inspect
import importlib
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]))
    if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, cmd_folder)

    # get the second argument from the command line
    methodname = sys.argv[1]

    # split this into module, class and function name
    modulename, classname, funcname = methodname.split(".")

    # get pointers to the objects based on the string names
    themodule = importlib.import_module(modulename)
    theclass = getattr(themodule, classname)
    thefunc = getattr(theclass, funcname)

    # pass all the parameters from the third until the end of what the function needs & ignore the rest
    args = inspect.getargspec(thefunc)

    print(args)
```

However, args in ArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None) shows an empty list.

1. How can I extract the parameters from either func1 or func2?
2. Is there a better way to run either func1 or func2 from the command line?

Comment: You do not need use `argparse` in func1 and func2, just write `def func2(name, number, greet)` like your given link.

Comment: You can also try the [python-fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire).

Comment: What kind of `parameters` are you seeking?  Neither of your functions takes an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). Here is an implementation of your example using sub-commands.

```
import argparse

def func1(args):

    print("Hi there {}, it is nice to meet you! You chose {}.".format(args.name, args.number))

def func2(args):

    print("{} there {}, it is nice to meet you! You chose {}.".format(args.greet, args.name, args.number))

#
# The top-level parser
#
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('top.py', description='An example sub-command implementation')

#
# General sub-command parser object
#
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

#
# Specific sub-command parsers
#
cmd1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', help='The first sub-command')
cmd2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('cmd2', help='The second sub-command')

#
# Assign the execution functions
#
cmd1_parser.set_defaults(func=func1)
cmd2_parser.set_defaults(func=func2)

#
# Add the common options
#
for cmd_parser in [cmd1_parser, cmd2_parser]:
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-n',   '--name',   default='host', help='Name of the user')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-num', '--number', required=True,  help='Number to report')

#
# Add command-specific options
#
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-g', '--greet', default='hello', help='Greeting to use')

#
# Parse the arguments
#
args = parser.parse_args()

#
# Invoke the function
#
args.func(args)
```

Example output:

```
$ python ./top.py cmd1 -n Mark -num 3    
Hi there Mark, it is nice to meet you! You chose 3.

$ python ./top.py cmd2 -n Bob -num 7 -g Hello
Hello there Bob, it is nice to meet you! You chose 7.
```

And, of course, the help functions work for each of the sub-commands.

```
$ python ./top.py cmd2 -h

usage: top.py cmd2 [-h] [-n NAME] -num NUMBER [-g GREET]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n NAME, --name NAME  Name of the user
  -num NUMBER, --number NUMBER
                        Number to report
  -g GREET, --greet GREET
                        Greeting to use
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put your first block of code in a file, I can import it into a `ipython` session and run your 2 functions:

```
In [2]: import stack49311085 as app
In [3]: app.simple
Out[3]: stack49311085.simple
```

`ipython` tab expansion (which uses some form of `inspect`) shows me that the module has a `simple` class, and the class itself has two static functions.

I can call `func1`, and get an `argparse` error message:

```
In [4]: app.simple.func1()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-n NAME] -num NUMBER
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: -num/--number
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Similarly for `func2`:

```
In [7]: app.simple.func2()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-n NAME] -num NUMBER [-g GREET]
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: -num/--number
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

`parse_args` as a default parses the `sys.argv[1:]` list, which obviouslly is not tailored to its requirements.

```
def foo(argv=None):
    parser = ....
    ....
    args = parse.parse_args(argv=argv)
    return args
```

is a more useful wrapper.  With this I can pass a test `argv` list, and get back the parsed `Namespace`.  If I don't give it such a list, it will used the `sys.argv` default.  When testing a parser I like to return and/or display the whole `Namespace`.

I haven't used `inspect` enough to try to figure out what you are trying to do with it, or how to correct it.  You don't need `inspect` to run code in an imported module like this.

---

I can test your imported parser by modifying the `sys.argv`

```
In [8]: import sys
In [9]: sys.argv
Out[9]: 
['/usr/local/bin/ipython3',
 '--pylab',
 '--nosep',
 '--term-title',
 '--InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False']
In [10]: sys.argv[1:] = ['-h']
In [11]: app.simple.func2()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-n NAME] -num NUMBER [-g GREET]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n NAME, --name NAME  name of the user
  -num NUMBER, --number NUMBER
                        choose a number
  -g GREET, --greet GREET
                        say greetings
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0
```

Or following the `help`:

```
In [12]: sys.argv[1:] = ['-num=42', '-nPaul', '-gHI']
In [13]: app.simple.func2()
...
---> 30         print("{} there {}, it's nice to meet you! you chose {}".format(args['greet'], args['name'], args['age']))
KeyError: 'age'
```

Oops, there's an error in your code.  You ask for `args['age']`, but didn't define a parser argument with that name.  That's part of why I like to print the `args` Namespace` - to make sure it is setting all the attributes that I expect.

---

Normally we don't use different parsers for different inputs.  It's possible to do that based on your own test of `sys.avgv[1]`, but keep in mind that that string will still be on `sys.argv[1:]` list that your parser(s) read.  Instead write one parser that can handle the various styles of input.  The `subparser` mentioned in the other answer is one option.  Another is to base your action on the value of the `args.greet` attribute.  If not used it will be the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was wondering about that when I saw your edit.