# Calling a python script from shell but passing the location of config file as a parameter

Tags: python, shell

How can I call a function from a python script (Ubuntu shell) but also pass a config parameter at the same time? A relevant SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line) does not seem to address that.

This is what I have for now:

```
$ python -c ' from python_library import * ; function() ; -config /path/to/config/file '
```

The above fails. And so do the following (as many other) combinations:

```
    $ python -c ' from python_library import * ; function() -config /path/to/config/file '
```

or

```
    $ python -c ' from python_library import * ; function() ; -config "/path/to/config/file" '
```

Thanks!

Comment: ` -config "/path/to/config/file"` is not python code, why are you including it in the quoted command

Comment: I am trying to pass a parameter (a config file) to my script, and the examples included in the original post are failed attempts to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the conf arg out as another argument to python

```
$ python -c ' from python_library import * ; function()' -config /path/to/config/file
```

Comment: it worked (without the lone  '-', that was included in your original post), thank you!

Comment: If you would like to add `&` at the end in order your command to run at the background and free up your shell prompt to issue another command?

Answer (score 1):

You could use environment variable for that:

```
MYPARAMETERS="-config /path/to/config/file" python -c "import os,sys;sys.argv = os.environ['MYPARAMETERS'].split(); import python_library import * ; function()"
```