# How to execute particular method say function2 in the following snippet or all three using command line arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

```
class dataVerifier:
    data_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome...")

    def function1(self):
        print("I am in function 1")     

    def function2(self):
        print("I am in function 2")

    def function3(self):
        print("I am in function 3")

Obj = dataVerifier()

Obj.function1()

Obj.function2()

Obj.function3()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/python-run-function-from-the-command-line . Might help?

Comment: How exactly do you want to use it? Can you give some example commands?

Comment: for example, if I pass args as " python sample.py -c  function2, function3, " then it should execute only function2 and function3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python -c 'from j import dataVerifier; ob = dataVerifier();ob.function1()'
```

`j` is the filename. This is for printing `function 1`. For printing all **3 functions** you can use:

```
$ python -c 'from j import dataVerifier; ob = dataVerifier();ob.function1();ob.function2();ob.function3()'
```

**Note**: Remember to be in the same directory.