# how to run multiple python methods separately in one file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file `hello.py` and multiple methods inside. My file looks like:

```
def method1():
    return data

def method2(args):
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method1()
    method2(args)
```

If I run `hello.py`, all methods run. But, how can I run these methods separately for example ?

Comment: You mean you want a module? Like `from hello import method1`?

Comment: When you run the file, the functions get defined but none of them are executed. You need to actually call `method1()` somewhere in the global scope.

Comment: yes I call these functions under `main` but how can I call one by one?

Comment: @JArunMani no all methods in one file please have a look?

Comment: Then as usual call them individually.

Comment: you can use `if input() == "1": method1(); else: method2()`

Comment: @JArunMani I dont have input but is it possible to write like `python hello.py --args=2`

Comment: @Nerd: You want to *run these methods separately* based on what ? Is it based on an user input ?

Comment: @codrelphi yes method1 does not have argument that's why when run `python hello.py` `method1()` should return data but next methods based on user inputs

Comment: Yep you can do that.

Comment: @JArunMani how can I do this? can you tell me please?

Comment: Please look at the answer I posted. Of course, there exists better solutions, but this one is simple enough to get things work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line you can, for example, run `method1`:

```
$ python -c 'import hello; hello.method1()'
```

or `method2`:

```
$ python -c 'import hello; hello.method2(somearg,someotherarg)'
```

This requires the command to be ran in the directory where `hello.py` is, or `hello.py` to be in PYTHONPATH.

Allowing flexibility, you can tweak the string and run any valid method with any valid argument as needed.

For more information, take a look at this answer on [how to run functions from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

So from your comments, I think you want this:

```
def method1(arg):
    print("hello", arg)

def method2(arg):
    print("Whatsup", arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    #print(sys.argv)
    func = sys.argv[1]
    arg = sys.argv[2]
    if func == "method1": method1(arg)
    elif func == "method2": method2(arg)
```

Now run this by `python3 hello.py method1 John`
This is a dirty example, if you want more options, you need to tweak a lot.