# how to call the methods as command arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sample program like

## File.py

```
def test1():
    print("test1")
def test2():
    print("test2")
def test3():
    print("test3")
def main():
    sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv[2]
    sys.argv[3]
 #   test1()
 #   test2()
 #   test3()

main()
```

I need to execute a command like "**python3 File.py test1() test2() test3()**"

some scenarios I need to  execute only one or two methods only "**python3 File.py test1() test2()**"

Comment: Can you make one function per file?

Comment: @MVB76 And then just import them seperately, making sure they are all in the same directory

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line

Comment: why not use `eval`?

Comment: @ impopularGuy can you give me detail info  on eval function. how can execute this command python3 File.py test1() test2() test3()  using eval

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for, but if you open the CMD in the directory your file.py is saved in, you can use:

```
python -i file.py
```

This will open the file in the interactive shell. You can then access the functions with a normal function call, like `test1()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would fill out the main function as follows:

```
arguments = list(sys.argv)
arguments.pop(0)
while arguments:
    function_name = arguments.pop(0)
    locals()[function_name]()
```

Then, in command line you type:

```
$ python3 file.py test1 test3 test2
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying that

  File "main.py", line 13, in main
    locals()["function_name"]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: My bad, sorry. Please remove the quotes around `function_name`, see fixed code.