# Pass function and arguments from node to python, using child_process

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I am new to child_process and I want to experiment with its capabilities.

Is there any way to pass a function and arguments to a python file, using spawn (or exec or execFile is spawn cannot do it)?

I want to do something like (pseudocode)

```
spawnORexecORexefile (python path/to/python/file function [argument1, argument2] )
```

or maybe

```
spawnORexecORexefile (python path/to/python/file function(argument1, argument2) )
```

Please explain and maybe give an example, because I am a newbie

How I am doing it now?

in node

```
 var process = spawn('python', [path/to/pythonFile.py, 50, 60] );
```

in `pythonFile.py`

```
import sys 
import awesomeFile

hoodie = int(sys.argv[1])
shoe = int(sys.argv[2])

awesomeFile.doYourMagic().anotherThing(hoodie, shoe)
```

as you can see, from node, I send data to `pythonFile` and then to `awesomeFile`, to a specific function

I would like to "cut the middle man" and remove the `pythonFile` and send data from node directly to the `awesomeFile` file, to a specific  function. This is why I am asking

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can run a specific Python function from the command-line using the form `python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987113/5666087).

Place both the files below in the same directory, and run with `node index.js`. You should see the following output:

```
Hoodie: 10
Shoe: 15
```

### `awesomeFile.py`

```
def myfunc(hoodie, shoe):
    hoodie = int(hoodie)
    shoe = int(shoe)
    print("Hoodie:", hoodie)
    print("Shoe:", shoe)
```

### `index.js`

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
let hoodie = 10,
    shoe = 15;
const result = spawn("python",
    ["-c", `import awesomeFile; awesomeFile.myfunc(${hoodie}, ${shoe})`])
result.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Bad news. I tested it and no matter how I syntax the `spawn` part in node, I get an error, spawn exits with code 1, ` Uncaught Fatal Exception - There was an uncaught exception, and it was not handled by a domain or an uncaughtException event handler.
` . What am I missing here ?

Comment: If I open a cmd and cd to a folder that contains a python file and try to do `python -c 'import test ; test.myFunc()'` I get ` File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: maybe its a syntax thing. The way you construct spawn maybe fits the `exec` better than the `spawn`, because your syntax its closer to shell syntax. Maybe `spawn` needs another syntax or other code entirely

Comment: Are you on windows? Can you try with double quotes? `python -c "import test ; test.myFunc()"`.

Comment: yes I am on windows. Wait, this isnt global for different OS? Anyway, I tried that and during the `result.on('exit'` I get exit code 2 `Unused (reserved by Bash for builtin misuse)`

Comment: Oh and btw this works for me in a Windows cmd `python -c "import testPY; testPY.myfunc()"`, really close to your last suggestion. Works in cmd, not in node spawn. I am kinda lost right now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can group all the relevant functions you want to call to class and make a dictionary out of a class that maps to the class function. You can directly call `awesome.py` without an intermediate `index.py`. You can extend the class `AwesomeFile` with your methods

The follow program will take user input -

1. which python file to run
2. which method to run
3. method arguments
4. Number of arguments mismatch
5. What if unknown methods are given

#### `awesomeFile.py`

```
import sys

class AwesomeFile:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def doYourMagic(self):
        return self
    
    def anotherThing(self, hoodie, shoe):
        print(int(hoodie))
        print(int(shoe))

awesomeFile = AwesomeFile()
methods = {m:getattr(awesomeFile, m) for m in dir(AwesomeFile) if not m.startswith('__')}

def run():
    method_name = sys.argv[1]
    if method_name not in methods:
        print(f"Unknown Method {method_name}")
        return
    methodArgCount = methods[method_name].__code__.co_argcount
    if methodArgCount - 1 != len(sys.argv[2:]):
        print(f"Method {method_name} takes {methodArgCount - 1} arguments but you have given {len(sys.argv[2:])}")
        return
    
    methods[method_name](*sys.argv[2:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

#### `index.js`

Note** - You would to install `prompt` - `npm i prompt`

```
'use strict';
var prompt = require('prompt');
const { spawn } = require( 'child_process' );

var prompt_attributes = [
    {        
        name: 'pythonFilePath'
    },
    {   
        name: 'cmdLineArgs'
    }
];

prompt.start();

prompt.get(prompt_attributes, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return 1;
    }else {
        console.log('Command-line received data:');
        var filePath = result.pythonFilePath;
        var cmdLineArgs = result.cmdLineArgs;
        var args = cmdLineArgs.split(" ");
        args.unshift(filePath);
        
        const pythonProgram = spawn( 'python' , args);

        pythonProgram.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
            console.log( `stdout:\n\n ${data}` );
        } );

        pythonProgram.stderr.on( 'data', data => {
            console.log( `stderr: ${data.data}` );
        } );

        pythonProgram.on( 'close', code => {
            console.log( `child process exited with code ${code}` );
        } );
    
    }
});
```

To run the program -

#### `I/O`:

Argument Mistmatch -

```
prompt: Python File Path. Give absolute or relative path: ../python_files/awesomeFile.py # python file can be any location in the system
prompt: Command Line Arguments. Format = func_name arguments_list (Ex addFunc 1 2):  anotherThing 1
Command-line received data:
stdout:

 Method anotherThing takes 2 arguments but you have given 1

child process exited with code 0
```

Function Not found

```
prompt: Python File Path. Give absolute or relative path:  ../python_files/awesomeFile.py
prompt: Command Line Arguments. Format = func_name arguments_list (Ex addFunc 1 2):  helloworld 1 2
Command-line received data:
stdout:

 Unknown Method helloworld

child process exited with code 0
```

Success Case:

```
prompt: Python File Path. Give absolute or relative path:  ../python_files/awesomeFile.py
prompt: Command Line Arguments. Format = func_name arguments_list (Ex addFunc 1 2):  anotherThing 50 60
Command-line received data:
stdout:

 50
60

child process exited with code 0
```