# Call python function inside a Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile and it has two parallel stages. In one stage I want to call a function from python script.

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
      stage('Main') {
        parallel {
          stage('Build') {
            steps {
              script {
                  ********I want to call python function here ********
              }
            }
          }
          stage('Test'){
              steps{
                  echo "It is a test stage."
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Python script:

```
class Build:

    def A():
        try:
            print("Build stage")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

I want to call this A() function there in my Jenkinsfile and want to get return value there.
Is there any mechanism to do this.

Comment: use `sh` or `bat` to start a python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line

Comment: I want to call the function in Jenkinsfile. sh or bat will only run the python script.

Comment: Then you need to convert the logic from Python into something Jenkins Pipeline can natively interpret, such as Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the logic in python script create object of class and call
   the method and return the value from method

> ```
> script {
>     sh"""
>     variable = python python_script.py
>     """
>     }
> ```