# Executing list of commands in one go on command line

Tags: python, command-line, plotly-dash

I am designing dash application which I am running from windows command line. I wanted to run it in go which is comprises of may instructions as follows:

1. create conda testenv
2. pip install dash, plotly, pandas and few more libraries
3. activate conda environment
4. python dash_file.py

Is there any easier way to do this? I am new to command line execution. I want to run it for non technical people where they can install and run everything in one go.

Comment: wait, you are running it one execution of the file, do you mean using only on function call to run all?

Comment: run all the above commands as one command or put all these commands in one file and execute it?

Comment: hmm, so like, u have a list of these string commands, then execute the whole list in one command?

Comment: correct, thats what I want to do on command line

Comment: why not use a function which takes the list, iterates through it using a for loop, then executes a command in every iteration, should i answer with this or you tried already?

Comment: But how to do this on command line?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function

```
def execute_all(commands):
    for command in commands:
        os.system(command)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line