# How can I call a function inside of a python file from command prompt?

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

For example, I have a python file named dave.py and I have created a function named clara within dave. Now, if I want to call clara  from command prompt, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this

```
python -c 'import dave; dave.clara()'
```

See this post for more information

[Run function from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line)