# is possible open python file with os.path.join and execute some function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I work with Django Framework, and I try to open a Python file from outside the Django package.
I use the OS library to get to the path that is outside the Django package, **like this**:

file_path = OS.path.join(settings.FILES_DIR, 'execute_get_symbols.py')

In file_path I got only the file path

**I want to run a function that is inside the file  "execute_get_symbols.py".**

**My questions are:**

- It is possible?
- And if it is possible, so how.
- And if it's not possible, So... how can I import files that are outside the Django package and execute the function?
  Like from package.file_name import function

Comment: maybe it's helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line

Comment: What do you mean by *"execute a function on this python file"* ?

Comment: check subprocess

Comment: I want to run a function that is inside the file  "execute_get_symbols.py" @HåkonHægland

Comment: I can't import to a package that is outside Django. @RaphaelMoralPiazera

Comment: simply executing it or use the function's output inside your script - like @Jisson said  the subprocess library is pretty straight forward. Other then that you might want to checkout relative imports

Comment: I try with relative imports, but it's not work. @Chris

Comment: I really don't understand, Python is python, you can import from another archive your functions . Maybe you can put the errors here and we can check and solve.

Comment: When I try to import
So it shouts to me "cannot import module __example_module_name__
And I think it happens because Django doesn't recognize the package that is outside of it. @RaphaelMoralPiazera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imoprt your file by adding it to sys.path (the list of paths python looks at to import things) - i believe that this is a kinda hacky way but still commonly used by django users:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path_to_your_file)
import your_file
```

Afterwards you should be able to use it normally

Comment: Hi, I tried the following code in the setting.py on Django

MANAGE_DB = os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent.parent, "manage_db")
I made sure that this is indeed the desired address

I made this import:   from manage_db.execute_get_symbols import get_symbols

and the error is:  
No module named 'manage_db.tools'; 'manage_db' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code in settings file on Django:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent.parent, ""))  # To get the path from root until current directory
```

And because of that, all the packages recognize on run time.