# Script doesn't execute when wrapped inside of a function

Tags: python, tesseract

When I execute the script below with `python3 ocr-test.py`, it runs correctly:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract'
# Simple image to string
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('receipt1.jpg')))
```

However, when I excute the below script with `python3 ocr-test.py process`, the process/function does not get called and nothing happens:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
def process():
   # If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
   pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract'
   # Simple image to string
   print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('receipt1.jpg')))
```

Why is this (not) happening?

Comment: The second example _defines_ a function but does not _call_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

to the bottom of the file.

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52837375/12172630).

Comment: may the gods smile upon you

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following code at the very end of your file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process()
```

The reason that `process` does not execute is because it is probably not called in your file. I have not seen anyone calling a function from command line before, and I do not think it is possible, except for running something like:

```
python -c "from ocr-test import process;process()"
```

but that is not common practice or recommended for that matter. Id stick with the first solution, but its up to you.